# TCP socket communication in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, sockets

The TCP socket programming code for NodeJs given at [link][1] works fine when server and client are on the same computer.
However when I run the client and server on two separate computers connected with a single Ethernet cable to the two Ethernet ports of the two computers, the client is unable to connect to the server! The have disabled the firewall on the server which is a 64 bit Windows 10 machine. The client is a 32 bit windows 7 old machine . When I start the server it starts, but when I connect the client with the IP address of the server and correct port number, it gives ECONNREFUSED error on the client)!

I am able to ping the two computers from each other. Also a Java based simple socket client and server programs are able to communicate with each other on the connection. But the NodeJs based TCP socket program given above doesn't work across the two computers. Any idea what could be the problem.
[1]: https://www.hacksparrow.com/nodejs/tcp-socket-programming-in-node-js.html

Comment: You need to show the code you're using to both set up the listener and establish the connection. If you bind to the loopback interface (`127.0.0.1`) you will *only* be able to receive local connections.

Comment: code is same as given in the above reference link, only thinng is that in the client code the HOST is give as the IP address of the server machine, the HOST in server remains 127.0.0.1 or <hostname>, I even tried to give the IP address of the server machine here: What should be the HOST address in that case for the server machine?

Comment: You need to bind to `0.0.0.0` to allow external connections.

Comment: Yessss... Thanks a lot tadman. You made my day!